# Linux (Debian 7 x64) swapping activity despite lots of free memory

Tags: linux, debian, swap

Yes, I have reduced vm.swappiness a lot:

```
% sysctl -a | grep swap
vm.swappiness = 1
```

Memory is mostly free:

```
% cat /proc/meminfo | head
MemTotal:        8070592 kB
MemFree:         2619580 kB
```

`ps_mem.py` (https://raw.github.com/pixelb/ps_mem/master/ps_mem.py) shows just 2.8 GB allocated, yet the system swaps a lot:

```
% vmstat  2
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
 1  3 3673808 3034600  34924 723456   13   19   297   210   16  132 33  9 56  3
 1  2 3671712 3027772  35984 721372 3248    0  4100   176 2185 3149 19 10 44 28
 1  2 3671048 3008808  35984 721256 9436    0  9436     0 3256 3507 18 10 42 30
 1  2 3670884 2994548  35984 721280 7120    0  7120     0 2734 2926 18 10 48 24
```

`free` output:

```
% free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7881       5881       1999          0        262        965
-/+ buffers/cache:       4653       3228
Swap:         7627       3023       4604
```

Comment: Swapping isn't a huge problem unless your system is running slow because of it.  The linux kernel swaps to free up memory.  So it may just be that memory is sitting idle in RAM so the linux kernel is swapping it out.